# 400 bad request in wordpress ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

This is my js code

```
// prepare ajax data 
        var data = {
            action: 'update_password',
            password: 'xyz',
            authToken: '123',
        };
        // fire ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: "POST",
            date: data,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('.update-pass').addClass('fa-spin fa-refresh');
                $('.update-pass').removeClass('fa-key');
            },
            success: function (responce) {
                responce = JSON.parse(responce);
                console.log(responce);
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('.update-pass').removeClass('fa-spin fa-refresh');
                $('.update-pass').addClass('fa-key');
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

and this php code from functions.php

```
    function update_password()
{
    echo "string";
    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_password', 'update_password');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_update_password', 'update_password');
```

**I have tried checking everything but always getting same 400 bad request error in browser console**

on the same js file i have another two ajax request code but they are working fine and they are in same format.

Thanks in advance

Comment: _A 400 Bad Request Error indicates that the server (remote computer) is unable (or refuses) to process the request sent by the client (web browser), due to an issue that is perceived by the server to be a client problem. ... If an expected custom HTTP header is missing or invalid, a 400 Bad Request Error is a likely result_

Comment: Do you localize the ajax script? see this post on wordpress.org ( https://wordpress.org/support/topic/admin-ajax-php-400-error/ ) which in addition to the steps you take also writes a hook to localize the ajax script and enqueue your script to the wordpress Ajax script, hope that makes sence.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296085/keep-getting-400-bad-request-error-when-trying-out-ajax-on-custom-theme

Comment: as i mentioned i have made another two request before in same file and they both are working fine. please help me how can i solve this in practical way ?

Comment: no i have create shortcode and used html and js there only. This way is also work with wordpress . so this is not an issue in my case

Comment: There's a typo in your code - you've got "date: data" - surely that should just be "data: data" - otherwise you'll never get the action to the endpoint.

Comment: OMG  !!!!! sorry for this guys i am wasting all of your time in such silly mistake ..Thank you so much and it's working now :)